# How can one generate pairs/triplets/.../n-ary MD5 collisions

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, md5

Is there a way to generate **n** strings with the same MD5 hash?

Answer (score 3):

MD5 is a Merkle–Damgård hash, so it's vulnerable to the [length extension attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack).

That means there's a simple way to find multicollisions using any algorithm that can find collisions for an arbitrary IV:

1. Find some collision $\operatorname{MD5}(a) = \operatorname{MD5}(b)$ using the normal IV.
2. Find another collision $\operatorname{MD5}'(c) = \operatorname{MD5}'(d)$ using the output from the first step as IV.
3. Combine them to valid messages that look like $a||c$, $a||d$, $b||c$ and $b||d$, except for the padding. This may require adding one more (equal) message block to get a valid padding and length.

Comment: A relevant paper (to the second part of the answer) is [Joux: _Multicollisions in Iterated Hash Functions. Application to Cascaded Constructions_](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-28628-8_19), in proceedings of CRYPTO 2004. $\;$ That's related to length extension attack, but not exactly it; rather, an extension.